# How can I automatically unlock and mount a ZFS pool at boot?

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, zfs, automounting

I was wondering if it's possible to automatically decrypt and mount a ZFS pool and its datasets at boot. Currently, I have to unlock the pool manually by using the command `# zfs load-key -a` and then run `# zfs mount -a`. It might also be worth mentioning that the "key", at the moment, is a passphrase (maybe it would be better to convert it to a keyfile and store it somewhere on the system?).

I'm running Ubuntu Server 23.04

Comment: One problem to ponder first, before implementing a method: if the secret is stored unencrypted, then encrypting the zfs pool becomes a bit less useful if the secret is nearby. I don't have an answer for this, but perhaps tools like clevis/tang could be used in a generic way (ie: not for LUKS) .

Comment: @A.B While what you are saying is true, the reason for me wanting to do it the way described in the OP is because I used to use TrueNAS before migrating to Ubuntu Server, so the datasets were automatically encrypted upon creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this myself.

1. First of all, after you've loaded the keys using `# zfs load-key -L file:///path/to/keyfile <pool>`, the key will stay loaded unless you explicitly unload it using `# zfs unload-key`.
2. In case you want to try to automatically load the key anyway, below'ss a quick systemd service I've written, but **be warned**: *the service will fail unless you unload the keys before rebooting*.

```bash
# /etc/systemd/system/zfs-load-key.service
[Unit]
Description=Load encryption keys
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=zfs-mount.service
After=zfs-import.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/zfs load-key -L file:///etc/zfs/zpool.key <pool-name>

[Install]
WantedBy=zfs-mount.service
```

3. There are a couple of ways to automatically mount the pool(s) at boot:

- Option #1: Using `zfs-mount.service`

```bash
sudo zpool set cachefile=/etc/zfs/zpool.cache <pool-name>
sudo systemctl enable --now zfs-import-cache.service
sudo systemctl enable --now zfs.target
sudo systemctl enable --now zfs-import.target
sudo systemctl enable --now zfs-mount.service
```

- Option #2: Using `zfs-mount-generator`

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache
sudo systemctl enable --now zfs.target
sudo systemctl enable --now zfs-zed.service
sudo touch /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache/<pool-name>
cat /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache/<pool-name> # if the file is empty, check that zfs-zed.service is running; if it is, run the command below
sudo zfs set canmount=off <pool-name>
cat /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache/<pool-name> # if the file has been updated, run the command below
sudo zfs set canmount=on <pool-name>

# A file needs to be (manually) created in `/etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache` for each ZFS pool in your system and ensure the pools are imported by enabling `zfs-import-cache.service` and `zfs-import.target`.
```

Comment: I don't understand the warning "the service will fail unless you unload the keys before rebooting." and haven't been able to replicate it. In what way does the service fail if you don't unload the key before rebooting?